# Sending an email from HIVE when a query is completed?

Tags: sql, hive

I am new to HIVE and have been unable to find an answer that helps without the use of add-ons or 3rd party stuff that adds to HIVE, which I can not use.

I currently have a few collegues in another location who run queries to update tables that are used during my day for some reporting.  I am trying to understand if there is something I can have them add to their SQL in HIVE that just sends an email to me, when the query is completed.  I do not need it to have any attachments or anything. Just simply let me know that the tables have been updated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is nothing in the HiveQL that will send an email.

A simple BASH script could accomplish what you're after.

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
beeline -u jdbc:hive2://NameNode:10000/my_db -q "SELECT col1, col2,col3 from db.table"
if [[ $? = 0]];then
    mail -s "Query Completed" me@example.com <<< 'Your query completed.'
else
    mail -s "Query Error" me@example.com <<< 'Something went wrong.'
fi
```

Comment: I like this approach could easily be adapted to run with a .hql file as an argument and email the name of the .hql in the message.

Comment: You could even capture the output of a query using --outputformat=csv2 and attach it to the email with mail -a.